# How to make right alignment when using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, horizontal-alignment

I use tikz to draw an image, below is part of the image. But the variable name is central alignment, how to make it right alignment?

[image]

Below is the related code

```
\foreach \i [count=\j from 1] in {5,4,3,2,1} {
\pic () at (-0.5,\i) {myarrow};
\node[xshift=-2.5cm] at (-1,\i) {VARIABLE NAME};
}
```

Comment: Off-topic-comment: You posted several questions recently, some of them have answers. Please consider accepting them!

Comment: Aha, i thought it is no necessary to vote. But, anyway,now the answer is done!

Comment: Voting and accepting are different. By accepting of answers you show that you appreciate the work by users here. Of course you don't need to upvote the answer additionally, but it's a nice feature if you do it anyway! Most users answering a question will also upvote the OP ;-)

Comment: replace `\node[xshift=-2.5cm]` by `\node[xshift=-2.5cm,anchor=east]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you seek? Use of `text width=the longest length and align=left,center, right` of your selections.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}%[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes}
\tikzset{myarrow/.pic = {
\begin{scope}[rotate=-90,scale=0.5]
\draw[fill=black] (-0.5,0) -- (0,0.5)--(0.5,0)--(0.5,1)--
(0,1.5)--(-0.5,1)--(-0.5,0) ;
\end{scope}},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (0,6);

% draw myarrows on the left side
\foreach \i/\k  in {5/{FUEL\_LEVEL\_TOT},4/{PBRAKE\_APPLIED\_HIGH},
3/{FUEL\_VOLUME},2/{FUEL\_LEVEL},1/{FUEL\_CONSUMPTION\_RATE}} {
\pic () at (-0.5,\i) {myarrow};
\node[xshift=-6cm,text width=8cm,align=right] at (-1,\i) {RTDB\_{\k}\_E};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```